# AEM/CQ5 package upload and deploy on remote server - Authentication issue (AEM 6.1)

Tags: maven, jenkins, aem

I am trying to install an AEM/CQ5 zip package on a remote server and getting an authorisation error (I am pretty sure I am putting the right credentials).
Also, the curl command just works fine:

curl -u : -F package=@-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip http://:/crx/packmgr/service.jsp/?cmd=upload -vvvv
* About to connect() to  port 4502 (#0)
*   Trying ...
* Connected to  () port 4502 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user

> POST /crx/packmgr/service.jsp/?cmd=upload HTTP/1.1
>   Authorization: Basic c2hhcmFkLmthcG9vcjpDb29raWVKYXIyMw==
>   User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
>   Host: 
>   Accept: */*
>   Content-Length: 10496181
>   Expect: 100-continue
>   Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------68858f7271d6
>
> < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   < Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2015 02:27:56 GMT
>   < Location: http://:/crx/packmgr/service.jsp/index.jsp
>   < Content-Length: 0
>   < Connection: close
>   < Server: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)
>   < X-Powered-By: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)
>   < 
>   * Closing connection 0

***Response***

{"success":true,"msg":"Package uploaded

**Whats failing is the Maven build from Jenkins server.**

Here is my pom settings:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.24</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetURL>http://${aem.host}:${aem.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
                    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <failOnMissingEmbed>true</failOnMissingEmbed>
                    <useProxy>false</useProxy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**And the error**

---

[DEBUG] Set parameter http.authentication.preemptive = true
[DEBUG] Proxying disabled (useProxy=false) or no proxies configured
[DEBUG] Set parameter http.connection.timeout = 30000
[DEBUG] Preemptively sending default basic credentials
[DEBUG] Authenticating with BASIC @:
[DEBUG] Credential charset not configured, using HTTP element charset
[DEBUG] Open connection to :
[DEBUG] >> "POST /crx/packmgr/service.jsp HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] Adding Host request header
[DEBUG] >> "referer: about:blank[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] >> "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] >> "User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] >> "Host: 52.64.163.101:4502[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] >> "Expect: 100-continue[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] >> "Content-Length: 10503730[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] >> "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=OpvAWdZ1OTJ_Xp9nZf9aKRDiC7BQTkw8NvdSNd[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] >> "[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] << "Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2015 03:20:33 GMT[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] << "WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Sling (Development)"[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] << "Server: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] << "X-Powered-By: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] << "[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] Authorization required
[DEBUG] Supported authentication schemes in the order of preference: [ntlm, digest, basic]
[DEBUG] Challenge for ntlm authentication scheme not available
[DEBUG] Challenge for digest authentication scheme not available
[INFO] basic authentication scheme selected
[DEBUG] Using authentication scheme: basic
[DEBUG] Authorization challenge processed
[DEBUG] Authentication scope: BASIC 'Sling (Development)'@:
[DEBUG] Credentials required
[DEBUG] Credentials provider not available
[INFO] Failure authenticating with BASIC 'Sling (Development)'@:
**[ERROR] Request to http://:/crx/packmgr/service.jsp failed, response=Unauthorized**
[DEBUG] Should close connection in response to directive: close
[DEBUG] Releasing connection back to connection manager.

---

I think the http.authentication.preemptive = true is causing the problem.
Is there any way to set this to false.
i have used Jenkins environment variable and I don't think we have any config parameters for com.day.jcr.vault.

Any thoughts on how to set this to false or any other suggestions to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To set preemptive authentication false, you can go to here:

http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr

Then search for: Apache Sling Authentication Service

Edit the configuration.

There is a dropdown for HTTP Basic Authentication, from which you can enable/disable the value.